# Поиск числа, имеющего наибольшее число делителей. C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, математика

Необходимо в заданном натуральном диапазоне(от 1 до бесконечности) найти число, имеющее наибольшее количество делителей. Как это сделать? C#

Comment: Похоже, перебором с разложением на простые...

Answer (score 2):

Держите ответ на вашу проблему

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
namespace ConsoleApp11
{
   class Program
   {
       static int kdel(int n)
       {
           int k = 0;
           for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
               if (n % i == 0)
                   k++;
           return k;
       }
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           int x, n,a,max,c;  
           n=int.Parse(ReadLine());
           max = 0;
           c = 0;
           for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
           {
               a = int.Parse(ReadLine());
               x = kdel(a);
               if (x > max)
               {
                   max = x;
                   c = a;
               }
           }
           WriteLine(c.ToString());
           ReadKey();            
       }
   }
}
```